# grouping images on ftp by date into folders in php

Tags: php, date, grouping, rename, directory

I would like to create a script in php which can help me organize jpg files taken from an IP camera. The camera saves pictures on my ftp server with a folder structure and name like:

```
/root/.../pictures/A14120121302310.jpg
```

I would like to create script that groups pictures into a folder - grouped by day.

I would like to run this script from remote location - router, notebook. Could you help me?
Here is my current code:

```
<?php
$dir    = '/';
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach($files as $file) {
$stat = stat($file);
$motdate = ($stat['ctime']);
$newname =  (gmdate("D d-m-Y_H-i-s", $motdate));
rename($file, $newname/$dir . $newname . ".jpg");
}
?>
```